# How to parse csv output requiring multiple matches using one-liner?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I have a scenario, where I have post-process / filter values taken out from DB. I'm using perl ple for the task. All works well until I come across extracted output (csv) which contains multiple `text` tags. See sample [here](http://www.pastebin.ca/2643350). The code works same (extract regex) correctly if there is just one text tag. In my db there are instances where there are more then one text files (i.e rule conditions).

The code is

```
echo "COPY (SELECT rule_data FROM custom_rule) TO STDOUT with CSV HEADER" | psql -U qradar -o /tmp/Rules.csv qradar;
perl -ple '
    ($enabled) = /(?<=enabled="").*?(?="")/g;
    ($group)   = /(?<=group="").*?(?="")/g;
    ($name)    = /(?<=<name>).*?(?=<\/name>)/g;
    ($text)    = /(?<=<text>).*?(?=<\/text>)/g;
    $_= "$enabled;$group;$name;$text";
    s/&lt;.*?&gt;//g;
' Rules.csv > rules_revised.csv
```

Just running the code on sample output I get following content in rule_revised file.

> true;Flow Property Tests;DoS: Local Flood (Other);when the flow bias
>   is any of the following outbound

Actually the line is truncated after **outbound** which infact should carry information similar to this..

> when at least 3 flows are seen with the same Source IP,
>   Destination IP in 5 minutes and when the IP protocol is one of the
>   following IPSec, Uncommon and when the source packets is greater than
>   60000

I **have tried** to correct this by making the regex greedy removing the `?` in $text but then it overflow all in-between `text` till the last `text` and at the end removing `lt;.*?>`messes the rest as it includes all the tag characters (i.e html) elements which I originally intended to dis include before making the regex greedy change.

Comment: Don't use a complex regex, use a proper XML parser to do the hard work for you.

Comment: Since you're already using perl, consider `DBI` and skip unnecessary shell clients, etc.

Comment: @user3066819 to start use [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm)/[DBD::Pg](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/DBD-Pg-3.0.0/Pg.pm) in place of command line clients, see [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.44/Twig.pm) or [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm)[Perl XML Tutorials](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=587266)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a truncated result with multiple matches is that you only store the first one.

```
($text)    = /(?<=<text>).*?(?=<\/text>)/g;
```

This only stores the first match. If you change that scalar to an array, you will capture all matches:

```
(@text)    = /(?<=<text>).*?(?=<\/text>)/g;
```

When you interpolate the array, it will insert spaces (the value of `$"`) between the elements. If you do not want that, you can change the value of `$"` to an acceptable delimiter. To be clear, you would change two characters to get the following lines:

```
(@text)    = /(?<=<text>).*?(?=<\/text>)/g;
...
$_= "$enabled;$group;$name;@text";
```

If I run your code on your sample with these changes the output looks like this:

> false;Flow Property Tests;DoS: Local Flood (Other);when the flow bias is any of the following outbound when at least 3 flows are seen with the same Source IP, Destination IP in 5 minutes when the IP protocol is one of the following IPSec, Uncommon when the source packets is greater than 60000

Comment: excellent:) I love how you worked out the solution for existing code. It worked like a charm:)

Comment: Its easy when you know how. :) You might check out the DBI module, like mpapec suggests, to write a program entirely in Perl that is more efficient and does not rely on a temp file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the `s`  modifier, it make the dot match newline:

```
perl -ple '
    ($enabled) = /(?<=enabled="").*?(?="")/g;
    ($group)   = /(?<=group="").*?(?="")/g;
    ($name)    = /(?<=<name>).*?(?=<\/name>)/g;
    ($text)    = /(?<=<text>).*?(?=<\/text>)/gs;
    #                                 here ___^
    $_= "$enabled;$group;$name;$text";
    s/&lt;.*?&gt;//g;
' Rules.csv > rules_revised.csv
```

Comment: There are no newlines in the sample input.